# suggestions to alert the end user when some thing goes bad

Tags: javascript, web-services, alert

What is the usual practice to notify the endusers for web interfaces that something has gone wrong in java script..
i am using alert method as below injava script...am looking for suggestions on better ways to do this?

```
        if (submitted = 'True' && submittedlist.length == ui_gerrits.length ){
            alert(submittedlist + ": gerrits already released in SU or Submitted for SU");                  
        }else if ((submitted = 'True') && (submittedlist.length != 0) ){
            alert(submittedlist + ": gerrits already released in SU or Submitted for SU \nPlease remove " + submittedlist + " and resubmit remaining gerrits");                 
        }
```

Comment: Personally, I like an all-red screen that says, "Missile Launched," and counts down from 30 seconds. Seriously, though, this is *way* too broad a question and too heavily opinion-based for this site.

Comment: While i do not know exactly what is and isnt accepted on UX stackexchange, this might belong on there as it is a user experience issue and not an actual programming one. Check [What questions can be asked on UX](http://ux.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: @EdCottrell - this is a java script programming query

Comment: @user2125827 Yes, but it's a very broad one, and the answers will be largely a matter of opinion. For those reasons, it's a poor fit for this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Normally use a framework like [Jquery Growl](http://ksylvest.github.io/jquery-growl/). This creates a simple way to handle all your page notifications and alerts. There are 100's of these frameworks and here are a couple:

1. [jQuery Growl](http://ksylvest.github.io/jquery-growl/)
2. [Noty](http://ned.im/noty/)
3. [Bootstrap Notify](http://bootstrap-growl.remabledesigns.com/)

Comment: i get an error `Uncaught ReferenceError: growl is not defined`

Comment: Did you define your Growl as this: `$(function() {
    $.growl({
      title: "Growl",
      message: "The kitten is awake!"
    });` Also, make sure you reference this library: `<script src="javascript/jquery.growl.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`

Comment: i have two files index.php and script.js ,where should add the part to reference this library...thanks for inputs so far

Comment: It's normally goes in your **<head>** section, reason being that if an error occurs during your AJAX calls etc, the notification library would of already been loaded and you can make use of it. Also make sure you reference your jQuery first then the **growl.js** and finally don't forget the css as well `<link href="stylesheets/jquery.growl.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />`

Comment: @Jacquest - is the paranthesis `$(function() { $.growl({ title: "Growl", message: "The kitten is awake!" });` closed properly,i see one outstanding `{`

Comment: @user2125827 Oh sorry man, it's missing a **})** ill update my comment quick, So this should fix that `$(function() { $.growl({ title: "Growl", message: "The kitten is awake!" }); });`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79074/discussion-between-user2125827-and-jacques-bronkhorst).

Answer (score 1):

The best practise is to avoid alerts. It is always a good usability if the user doesn't have to headle program errors. But if it is not possible to avoid alerts, you can show him the error in a css styled div block or you create your own alert/dialog window with frameworks or javascript.
If you want to use javascript take a look [here](http://blog.raventools.com/create-a-modal-dialog-using-css-and-javascript/).
Good luck!